# ui-sref with multiple parameters to child view not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular's ui-router on my application to try and route to child views of a main view. Both the main and the child have their own associated IDs. Currently I can navigate to the parent, but my link to the child is not working.

In my Application.js

```
$stateProvider

//Working Route
.state('Project', {
    url: '/Project/{projectId}',
    views: {
        "ContentMain" : { 
            templateUrl: "/Scripts/Dashboard/templates/MainContent/ProjectMainContent.html", 
            controller: function ($stateParams) {
                console.log("Project state hit!"); 
            }
         },
        ...
    }
})

//Non-Working Route
.state('Project.ViewResource', {
    url: '/Resource/:resourceId',
    parent: 'Project',
    views: {
        "ContentMain" : { 
            templateUrl: "/Scripts/Dashboard/templates/MainContent/ProjectResourceViewContent.html" 
            controller: function ($stateParams) {
                console.log("Project.ViewResource state hit!"); 
            }
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

In my HTML:

```
<!-- Working Link-->
<a ui-sref="Project({ projectId: 5 })"><h3>   My Projects </h3></a>

<!-- Non-working Links -->
<a ui-sref="Project.ViewResource({ projectId: 5, resourceId: 3 })">View Project Resource. </a>
<a ui-sref="Project.ViewResource({ resourceId: 3})">I'm a Resource Image. </a>
```

The first link works, however when I click either of the "non-working" child links my browser updates to: "Home/Index/#/Project/5/Resource/3" which is the desired route, however the page content

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

**Edit1**: To add the lines of code in the 'views' object which should be swapping out.

**Edit2:** To further demonstrate the issue, I've added the controller code blocks. When I hit the first html link, my console outputs "Project state hit!"  When I click either of the non-working links, there is no new output to the console. Ie, the route is likely not being hit.

Comment: Can I see the markup for the parent and child views please?

Comment: I added the view I'm trying to change here to the code. However, I won't add the contents of the child views because a) clutter and b) the problem isn't in there. Ui-Router isn't hitting the route I specified.

Comment: You state in your post that the correct URL is hit. `When I click the link my browser updates to: "Home/Index/#/Project/5/Resource/3" which is the desired behavior, however the page is remaining on my Project route.` That could very much be a problem with the placement of the parent's `ui-view`.

Comment: Does the parent view have an `ui-view` on it?

Comment: Yes. I'm using 4 seperate views for each state, and these are only 2 out of the 5 states currently using these ui-views. 4 of the states (including "Project") are transitioning with no problem. The 5th state, my only child state, is not being hit.

Comment: On the non working route, try an absolute url like so: `^/Project/{projectId}/Resource/{resourceId}`.

Comment: Switched Project.ViewResource to `url: '/Resource/:resourceId'` and still having the same problems. Also, I changed my first page to `$state.transitionTo('Project.ViewResource');` in my `.run` block and it's hitting the console output from the Project state. Which leads me to believe that the problem is some sort of overlapping..

Comment: What happens if you remove "parent: 'Project'"? Doesn't ui-router figure that out since you have a '.' in the state name?

Comment: @aet Yes, it's implied from the state name, but no removing it doesn't make any kind of difference.

Comment: Where did you find that syntax for view declaration, or is it something you came up with? I'm looking at ui-router docs, and it looks like you would just need to move the templateUrl and controller to the top level of the state object.

Comment: @aet It's part of their documentation. 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: Wow, thanks, don't know how I missed that! If you use an href to get to that view, does it work? As opposed to the ui-sref? Just trying to narrow down where the problem is...

Comment: No, using `<a href="#/Project/5/Resource/3">` doesn't let me hit the controller for the child.

To clarify, the problem I'm having his that using a route like `#/Project/5/Resource/2` hits the parent controller, but NOT the child controller, as tested by the console.log statements.

Comment: Ahh.. Solved it. Answer to follow shortly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured out what was happening. After taking a closer look at the document on multiple named views [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views), I realized that my child view was searching for ui-view tags within the *parent* template, rather than the *root* template. Essentially, my child was trying to nest within my parent, while my desired behavior was to replace the parent views.

So, to target ui-views within the root, my solution looked like:

```
.state('Project.Resource', {
    url: '/Resource/{resourceId}',
    parent: 'Project',
    views: {
        "MainControls@":   { templateUrl: "/Scripts/Dashboard/templates/MainControls/MainControls.html" },
        "ContentMain@": {
            ...
         },
         ...
     }
})
```