# ui-sref with multiple named views usig ui-router

Tags: html, view, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui-router` and working on multiple named views. However, I am unable to add a hyperlink which navigates from one view to another brand new view.

I am trying to add implementation for links (ex: link1, link2) available at 
http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/JYdXVa

I tried below two approaches but are not working

```
 <a ui-sref="newView" >Link 1</a>

 <a ui-sref="parentState.child" >Link 1</a>
```

I spent lot of time on googling and experiments but unable to figure out solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `ui-view` on the index page just once for the content that needs to be loaded. Include navigation and footer with `ng-include="templates/nav.html"` on the index site.

Comment: header and footer are just examples I selected. My project has different business functionality to display. I just selected this as a reference. I can not avoid usage of multiple views in my project

Comment: [Solution for ui-sref with named views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415170/ui-sref-with-multiple-parameters-to-child-view-not-working)

Comment: [ui-sref with named views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415170/ui-sref-with-multiple-parameters-to-child-view-not-working) Please visit above link for solution

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do, exactly, but here is an edit of that pen you posted with the nav links working.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLWLMp

Note that I defined a new rout (you need to define a route for each 'page' you want to have)

```
$stateProvider.state('body2', {
  url: '/body2',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: './templates/body2.html'
    },
    'nav': {
      templateUrl: './templates/assets/nav.html'
    },
  }
});
```

Also, I added the ui-sref attributes to the nav anchors:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="./templates/assets/nav.html">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a ui-sref="body2">Body 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </script>
```

And finally, I changed the home route somewhat because I don't think it makes much sense to have a `ui-view="nav"` in both the main- and the home template for this example.

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed reply. This is working fine and gave answers to my questions.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) now if you would accept my answer i would be even more glad ;)